# How to implement collect view in cooja for RPL skymote

Tags: c, iot, contiki

Can anybody tell me how to implement `collect-view` for 
`contiki-2.7/examples/ipv6/simple-udp-rpl/unicast-receiver.c` ?

Do I have to refer to

> contiki-2.7/examples/ipv6/rpl-collect/collect-common.c & udp.sink.c

or

> contiki-2.7/examples/collect collect-view-shell.c

?

Comment: I formatted your question so it is more readable. I also made a sentence and remove 'plz help', as if you are asking a question, you are obviously asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you already added header file and use sky mote for your simulation. As I know, collection view application is only working on Sky motes.